# 2 disks on nvme, one is visible, one is not

Tags: dual-boot

Hi I have problem with my pc, have 2 disc ADATA_LEGEND_960V 1tb and adata s40g 500gb booth on nvme
In legend have windows 11 and on s40g want to install ubuntu or mint but installer don't see s40g only legend, switching from ahci to raid do nothing, ubuntu not support intel rst. windows 11 installer dont have any problems with detect booth of my disk. configuration is the same, why debian. mint, and ubuntu not detecting it?
motherboard  msi z590 ace, swaping or remove disks is not an option.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome 
if you don't want to use a Linux Mint forum. (One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Linux Mint so take advantage of it's support options, or SE Unix & Linux)  Note that I installed Kubuntu 22.04 and it used the Intel VMD driver for RAID on with my laptop. You also need UEFI & NVMe firmware fully updated.

Comment: i found this" nvme 0000:03:00.0: unable to change power state from d3cold to d0 device inaccessible.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1942624

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Comment: No this is a core bug, there is no solution.

Comment: "*ubuntu not support intel rst*" Wrong: It's the other way around. Intel RST does not provide Linux support. RST is proprietary, and the owner (Intel) has decided to deny the Linux kernel a license. Complain to Intel.

Comment: no, I don't use rst mode.

Comment: You wrote this so bad.  I have no clue understanding what you mean.  I think you are a kid and that is fine.  So you want to use the Optane stick as a SSD or just storage?

Why would switching ahci to raid do anything?  I would not suggest you even play with that unless you want to lose your data.  Raid is for when you have more than one disk and you want it to appear as if it was one.  When you change the confederation it has to wipe it clean. ACHI is what you want to use if you want it to appear as one. 

So your question is RTS and installing the base operating system that is Ubuntu?

Comment: I would say try to disable the BIOS/UEFI fast boot and secure boot to see if that makes a different.  It could be because your SSD is failing and thus it refuse to mount it.  Open up the Disk utility i.e. "gnome-disks" and see if you can see it or do "sudo lsblk" in the terminal.